# Converting integer to binary string using itoa in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, itoa

Can I use `itoa()` for converting long long int to a binary string?

I have seen various examples for conversion of int to binary using `itoa`.  Is there a risk of overflow or perhaps loss of precision, if I use long long int?

## Edit

Thanks all of you for replying. I achieved what I was trying to do. `itoa()` was not useful enough, as it does not support long long int. Moreover I can't use `itoa()` in gcc as it is not a standard library function.

Comment: AFAIK, `itoa` converts an integer to a string..... Could you provide some sample code from those examples that you mentioned?

Comment: `itoa` is not a standard function. Also, do you mean you want to convert an integer to a string with only binary digits?

Comment: @SayemAhmed- Here's the link which says i can convert int to binary string.http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/

Comment: mask out the bits and construct a binary string yourself.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - Yes, Exactly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert an integer to a string containing only binary digits, you can do it by checking each bit in the integer with a one-bit mask, and append it to the string.

Something like this:

```
std::string convert_to_binary_string(const unsigned long long int value,
                                     bool skip_leading_zeroes = false)
{
    std::string str;
    bool found_first_one = false;
    const int bits = sizeof(unsigned long long) * 8;  // Number of bits in the type

    for (int current_bit = bits - 1; current_bit >= 0; current_bit--)
    {
        if ((value & (1ULL << current_bit)) != 0)
        {
            if (!found_first_one)
                found_first_one = true;
            str += '1';
        }
        else
        {
            if (!skip_leading_zeroes || found_first_one)
                str += '0';
        }
    }

    return str;
}
```

**Edit:**

A more general way of doing it might be done with templates:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cassert>

template<typename T>
std::string convert_to_binary_string(const T value, bool skip_leading_zeroes = false)
{
    // Make sure the type is an integer
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "Not integral type");

    std::string str;
    bool found_first_one = false;
    const int bits = sizeof(T) * 8;  // Number of bits in the type

    for (int current_bit = bits - 1; current_bit >= 0; current_bit--)
    {
        if ((value & (1ULL << current_bit)) != 0)
        {
            if (!found_first_one)
                found_first_one = true;
            str += '1';
        }
        else
        {
            if (!skip_leading_zeroes || found_first_one)
                str += '0';
        }
    }

    return str;
}
```

Note: Both `static_assert` and `std::is_integral` is part of C++11, but is supported in both Visual C++ 2010 and GCC from at least 4.4.5.

Comment: The leading zeros could be easily avoided. Just skip the 0s until we see the first 1 (when scanned from left to right).

Comment: @AndreasMagnusson Added argument to skip leading zeroes. :)

Comment: Thanks A lot Joachim Pileborg ! Modified your code so that i can use it in c and it worked like a charm ! :) :)

Comment: If doing a C version, you could change `current_bit = 63` to `current_bit = ((sizeof value) * 8) - 1`

Comment: I don't see how the template version works, where does `bits` variable come from?

Comment: @Prof.Falken Oops, forgot that! Weird that no-one noticed that omission for two and a half years. :)

Comment: Ahem... not weird. Please accept the harsh reality that templates in C++ makes your eyes kind of gloss over and you start thinking about something else, like what you had for dinner last night or... look shiny! :)

Comment: Well, now that I saw your fix for bits in the templates version, consider adding it to your other version too: `current_bit = ((sizeof value) * 8) - 1`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. As you [showed yourself](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/), itoa can be called with base 2, which means binary.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    char str[33];

    i = 37; /* Just some number. */
    itoa (i, str, 2);
    printf("binary: %s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Also, yes, there will be truncation if you use an integer type larger than int, since itoa() takes only plain "int" as a value. long long is on your compiler probably 64 bit while int is probably 32 bit, so the compiler would truncate the 64 bit value to a 32 bit value before conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Your wording is a bit confusing,
normally if you state *'decimal'* I would take that to mean: *'a number represented as a string of decimal digits'*, while you seem to mean *'integer'*.

and with *'binary'* I would take that to mean: *'a number represented as bytes - as directly usable by the CPU'*.

a better way of phrasing your subject would be: converting 64-bit integer to string of binary digits.

some systems have a `_i64toa` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) for this purpose

```
template<typename T>
inline std::string to_binary_string(const T value)
{
    return std::bitset<sizeof(T)>(value).to_string();
}

std::cout << to_binary_string(10240);
std::cout << to_binary_string(123LL);
```